# How to write the mathematical equation for this model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have a nested mixed effects model as follows:

```
lmer(log(Weight) ~ Gender + (1 | SubjectID / MeasurementID))
```

I have subjects who have two separate measurements of their weight, therefore I have a nested model where measurementID is nested within SubjectID, but I am not sure how to represent it mathetmatically.

Answer (score 8):

If you have only two measurements per subject, then it would be more logical to first start with only one random intercept, i.e.,

$$\log(\texttt{Weight}_{ij}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{Gender}_i + b_i + \epsilon_{ij},$$

where $b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_b^2)$ denotes the random intercept for the $i$-th subject, and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ denote the error terms.

The corresponding syntax with `lmer()` is:

```
lmer(log(Weight) ~ Gender + (1 | SubjectID), data = <your_data>)
```

The model you’re trying to fit should not be identifiable because the nested random effect for each measurement collides with the error terms.